# How to replace multiple strings in html in order to wrap items in a jsx component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

I have WordPress content for my blog, which looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Bla 1</li>
<li>Bla 2</li>
<li>Bla 3</li>
<li>Bla 4</li>
<li>Bla 5</li>
<li>Bla 6</li>
</ul>
```

I need to replace `<ul>` and `</ul>` with a React opening and closing component tags so that I could display a "show more" (react-show-more-text node package) button after a couple of list items.

I tried doing that using react-string-replace node package, however it can perform only one regex operation per line, and I can't return a non closed JSX component:
First regex line would be to replace `<ul>` with , to end up with:

```
 <ShowMoreText>     
    <li>Bla 1</li>
    <li>Bla 2</li>
    <li>Bla 3</li>
    <li>Bla 4</li>
    <li>Bla 5</li>
    <li>Bla 6</li>
    </ul>
```

However, I can't do a second regex because I can't return a non-complete JSX code - I need to include a closing tag for .

Is there any way to return a non-complete JSX code and then complete it on the second regex run? Or am I doing this completely wrong and If so - what would be the best way to do this?

Edit: WordPress content doesn't always begin with `<ul>`, so it would be best if the solution included a way to process an entire blog post, and return with `<ul>` replaced with `<ShowMoreText>`, and `</ul>` with `</ShowMoreText>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) to convert the html string to `JXS` elements. Use the `replace` function to replace the `UL` nodes for other elements and `domToReact` to render it's children:

```
import parse, { domToReact } from "html-react-parser";

const text = `<div><ul>
                  <li>Bla 1</li>
                  <li>Bla 2</li>
                  <li>Bla 3</li>
                  <li>Bla 4</li>
                  <li>Bla 5</li>
                  <li>Bla 6</li>
                </ul></div>`;

  const render = () => {
    return parse(text, {
      replace: ({ tagName, children }) => {
        if (tagName === "ul") {
          return <ShowMoreText>{domToReact(children)}</ShowMoreText>;
        }
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      {render()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ukvjmz?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: That's great, I just think that this doesn't work if there's anything before <ul> tag.

This just returns  <ShowMoreText> <inner list items> </ShowMoreText>

What if I have (most likely on any blog post) some content before the list, could I use this?

<content before ul>
<ul>
<li>Bla 1</li>
<li>Bla 2</li>
</ul>
<content after ul>

Comment: I updated again, I think it is more clear now